# Using Linux clocks in an embedded design

Tags: linux, clock, arm64

I am using Linux on Xilinx RFSOC (arm64; 4 cores running in SMP mode). I am using the Linux provided by the Xilinx tool chain (PetaLinux 2019.2) which uses kernel version 4.19, with gcc 4.7.4.0.

I need to use clock services for time stamping and for sleeping.

I have the following requirements:
a) A consistent clock value across all cores returned from clock_gettime
b) Availability of high-resolution (<= 1 us) timestamps
c) Availability of high-resolution (1 us) preemptive sleep
d) Clock should not be affected by NTP, GPS leap seconds, etc.
e) Minimal clock sampling overhead (for clock_gettime)

Notes:
a) I specifically do not need the clock to reflect current UTC time. I just need it to be monotonic.
b) The system is never suspended

Linux defines several clocks (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html). Of these the following seem to be relevant to my needs:
CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, CLOCK_BOOTTIME

Regarding CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE it says that it is fast but less precise than CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

Documentation for nanosleep says that on Linux it is based on CLOCK_MONOTONIC and that it is not affected by NTP, etc.

I know that calling clock_gettime on some of all of the above avoids a system call (on later Linux versions).

I have the following questions:
a) Which of the above clocks best complies with my requirements listed above?
b) What is the resolution of the above clocks on arm64 for clock_gettime?
c) What is the effective resolution of nanosleep?

Thanks,

Comment: Criterion d) excludes everything but `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` in the options you gave. Unfortunately you cannot have a consistent clock value across all cores per your criterion a). At best you could compute estimates of the skew and drift rates of each clock w.r.t. each other and use them in a wrapper. This is made more complicated by dynamic frequency scaling, which may happen independently on each core.

Comment: Are you saying that if I want (a) then I must use CLOCK_REALTIME?

In such case, what is the effective resolution of this clock for clock_gettime (does it provide microsecond-resolution (at least))?
 How does its overhead compare with that of CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW?

Comment: *None* of the options available to you have high-resolution consistent values across all cores. The kernel makes an effort, but it might not be good enough for you. If you need extremely close agreement between the timestamps of several cores you must compute and maintain that agreement yourself.

Comment: If timestamp consistency across cores cannot be guaranteed for the MONOTONIC clocks, the best (or only) option to implement a usable real-time clock will be via a "hardware" register in the programming logic. Is that indeed the case (i.e. ARM/MPSOC does not provide a usable high-resolution clock that is shared across all cores)?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no such shared clock exists, and the best that can be done is some synchronization protocol like thread A sampling a timestamp Ta, writing it to M, having thread B exchange it for Tb as soon as it sees M change, and thread A can then sample another timestamp and compute the delta between the two cores.

Comment: I presume that this problem should also occur when using CLOCK_REALTIME. You wrote that the kernel attempts to present a consistent clock across all cores, however the result may not be perfect.

Comment: What kind of deviation can we reasonably expect between clock readings on different cores?